# Is an unkind comment flag declined after deleting the answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, deleted-answers, comment-flags, code-of-conduct

A user posted an answer to a pretty unclear question:

> I am a nice person. Lots of other on stack overflow would down vote this question.
>
> You have to [rest of answer]

I edited the answer to remove the first sentence, then commented why [rest of answer] was incorrect, then downvoted the answer because it was incorrect.

Later, the user posted a comment under that answer:

> You must [repetition of answer] IDIOT

I flagged that comment for being "Unfriendly or unkind", and noticed the answer was at -4 and had a delete vote, and cast another delete vote because it didn't seem like the answer nor the discussion were going anywhere, and a few minutes later the answer was deleted by the delete vote of a third user.

Now the comment flag is marked "declined". Was that an automatic action because the answer was deleted, or a manual action where a moderator didn't agree that calling someone an "IDIOT" is unfriendly or unkind?

Link to deleted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57854371.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know the reasons behind it; but I have an understanding that in 23 hours that account will no longer exist.  I'll check deeper and see what's going on.

Comment: It may well be the reviewer only saw the [repetition of answer] and just missed the IDIOT at the end

Comment: @George given their tone I'd guess they're a troll user of some kind. Glad someone noticed. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I assume they meant the *Integrated Digital Input/Output Toolkit* ...

Comment: @Nick I'd hope that given my flagging history (295 comment flags of which 7 were declined, 1 of which in the past 8 years) my flags would be given some more consideration, but eh.

Comment: I don't think the mod has that info then they handle the flag.

Comment: @rene that'd be a shame. I thought I've read somewhere that your flagging stats gave some weight to your flags, either whether they'd turn up higher in the queue or were visibly marked as a "trusted flagger" or something.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, I'm at 170 comment flags, 1 declined (a NLN on a now deleted question, but hey-ho), can't expect anything for good history, mods have to treat every flag on it's own, without knowing history, a good flagger can't be assumed to always flag well

Comment: I'm over 6,000 comment flags. I still get declined flags.

Comment: We don’t see your stats when handling flags. I’m torn as to whether it would be useful. It would be more useful to me than reputation, which we do show. I’d love an experiment on this to see.

Comment: @NickA yes, it that a problem? I try to convey with that number that you shouldn't be bothered too much about how many flags you already have. Flagging still has that lottery aspect in it ...

Comment: @rene Of course not, you know me, my comment was tongue in cheek :)

Comment: The person's behaviour was unacceptable - they had optioned to delete their own account. I kindly sped up that process and deleted it immediately and issued a long suspension on the master account. It turns out this rude account was created to circumvent post bans. I can't speak for the mod who declined the comment flag, I suspect they didn't notice the "idiot" at the end of the comment. Also fun fact: an deleted post will validate all active comment flags under that post.

Comment: @rene I do try... :P (to decline your flags) <--- joke for anyone who doesn't know us

Comment: Fun fact: I also submitted the same flag on that comment, and it too was declined. That makes 1042 comment flags, 14 declined for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm the moderator who manually declined the flag (deleting a post clears spam/NAA/VLQ flags but doesn't clear any of the comment flags).

The comment read:

> You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' - IDIOT

I wrongly assumed that this user was treating themselves as an "IDIOT", like it often happens

> "Oh I didn't see this, stupid"

using "You" as themselves. I know it's far fetched but that's how I read it. Well, it was so blatant I didn't imagine it could be directed to someone else...

Generally insults to other users are more, erm *colorful*..., and the comment doesn't contain technical information either.

I assumed wrong, I should have read the whole thread before dismissing. We're dismissing a lot of "auto" flags where the bot fails to see the self-depreciation of users who realize their fault.

Now I'm not sure if I dismissed an auto flag or one of your manual flags. FYI I dismissed 2 flags and accepted 2 others on the same thread. Maybe a bot is more reliable than me sometimes...:

```
1 hour ago  CodeCaster  comment flag: Unfriendly or unkind  1 hour ago  Jean-François Fabre♦    Unfriendly or unkind    Declined
1 hour ago  <some other poor victim>    comment flag: Unfriendly or unkind  1 hour ago  Jean-François Fabre♦    Unfriendly or unkind    Declined
1 hour ago  <lucky you>     comment flag: Unfriendly or unkind  1 hour ago  Jean-François Fabre♦    Unfriendly or unkind    Helpful
1 hour ago  <lucky you>     comment flag: Unfriendly or unkind  1 hour ago  Jean-François Fabre♦    Unfriendly or unkind    Helpful
```

Keep flagging those as you did. You did okay.

Comment: No problem, glad to know the explanation and that the system won't decline flags in this scenario. I know your workload is high and the context low, so keep up the good work.

Comment: oh, no deleting the answer doesn't clear the comment flags. I have edited my answer

Comment: I had the same issue as @CodeCaster -- my flag on the very same comment was declined (perhaps by you as well)

Comment: yes, I did that too, sorry. I didn't understand why the flag popped up twice :)

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for bringing this to our attention, this has been handled.

In the future, do exactly what you did here.  I can't speak for why it wasn't caught, but [Nick A's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389234/unkind-comment-flag-declined-after-deleting-the-answer?noredirect=1#comment726632_389234) seems like a reasonable interpretation of events:

> It may well be the reviewer only saw the [repetition of answer] and just missed the IDIOT at the end – Nick A 11 mins ago

Comment: I do assume the mod see the  whole comment at once? Or has that been sacrificed in the new responsive make over?

Comment: @rene I've reached out to the moderator to have them write an answer; I don't know what actions led to it being declined. I do know that we do see the whole comment.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. You never know these days if the aesthetics go over function ... ;)